# recuperar valor de atributo data-id de boton html y bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Tengo un botón en cada fila de una tabla con el atributo data-id el cual es diferente al de las demás filas

```
<button id="btnCancelar" class="btn btn-warning" data-id="@item.facturaCancelacion">Ok</button>
```

en un archivo JS tengo un evento click para recuperar el data-id que selecciono al presionar el botón.

```
    $('#btnCancelarFactura').on('click',function () {
        alert($(this).data("id"));
    });
```

el problema es que solo el botón de la primera fila me recupera el valor data-id, como puedo recuperar el valor de las demás filas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No creo que este ahí el problema, al parecer estas usando el `id` en los botones.

Estas usando el selector `#` o selector ***por id***: `$('#btnCancelarFactura')`, pero este selector devuelve 0 o 1 elementos, no multiles. Significa que solo el primer elemento encontrado con `id="btnCancelarFactura"` instala el manejador y lo demás no lo instalan; esta hecho así pues, se supone que los `ids` sean únicos.

Hay dos opciones, un selector por multiple por el attriute `id`: *notese* `[id=btnCancelarFactura]`

```js
$('button[id=btnCancelarFactura]').on('click',function () {
  alert($(this).data("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnCancelarFactura" class="btn btn-warning" data-id=".234">1...</button>
<button id="btnCancelarFactura" class="btn btn-warning" data-id=".678">5...</button>
<button id="btnCancelarFactura" class="btn btn-warning" data-id=".012">9...</button>
```

o usar una clase, exclusiva para estos botones "cancelar" y seleccionar los elementos, aquí el id no lo necesitas.

```
<button class="btn btn-warning mibtn-cancelar" ... >
<button class="btn btn-warning mibtn-cancelar" ... >
```

Luego usas el selector de clases y tomas todos los botones.

```
$('.mibtn-cancelar').on('click',function () {
    alert($(this).data("id"));
});
```

Te faltaba poco, te recomiendo siempre asegurarse via debugger que el selector esta tomando todos los elementos que se espera que seleccione.

Answer (score 4):

Estas definiendo el `eventHandler` a un solo item `btnCancelarFactura`, lo que debes hacer es cambiar por una `clase` en lugar de un `id` (HTML)

Revisa el siguiente código para que tengas la idea:

```js
 $('.btn').on('click',function () {
        alert($(this).data("id"));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnCancelarA" class="btn btn-warning" data-id="A">Ok</button>
<button id="btnCancelarB" class="btn btn-warning" data-id="B">Ok</button>
<button id="btnCancelarC" class="btn btn-warning" data-id="C">Ok</button>
```

Comment: ojo que si usas `.btn` como selector podrias atacharte a otros botones no relacionados.

Answer (score 2):

> Tengo un botón en cada fila de una tabla con el atributo data-id el cual es diferente al de las demás filas

Bien, entonces olvidate de usar ID. Usa clases.

```
<button class="btnCancelarFactura btn btn-warning" data-id="@item.facturaCancelacion">Ok</button>
```

Y en JS:

```
$('.btnCancelarFactura').on('click',function () {
    var dataId = $(this).attr("data-id");
    alert($(this).attr("data-id"));
});
```

Te dejo el ejemplo funcionando:
https://jsfiddle.net/gxLmtc88/2/

Un saludo

Edit: te he ampliado el ejemplo a varios botones.